# Custom CSS in SAPUI5 Application

Tags: sapui5

i have a question based in this:

[Design of SAP Fiori/UI5 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686233/design-of-sap-fiori-ui5-application?rq=1)

i load my css like this in my manifest.json:

```
"resources": {
    "css": [{
            "uri": "css/custom.css",
            "id" : "customcss"

    }]
},
```

so my css only will affect the elements and not the theme ? or the theme in fiorilaunchpad will affect everything ignoring my css?

Comment: What are those *elements* you want to change with your custom CSS? Is it about fixing cosmetic bugs? Do you want to change some colors? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is quite powerful and you can pretty much change anything you want, including the existing SAP themes, if you decide to change properties in the existing standard classes (normally beginning with "sap").

See it this way: Fiori always loads a standard theme first and applies its styles to the existing controls based on the Fiori UX and Guidelines. Now you can pretty much change anything in your CSS you want to overwrite, but be aware that you easily break things like responsiveness if you change size properties like width/height of controllers.

I would only use CSS in combination with custom classes on my controls and only change things that do not interfere with the sizing/layouting of controls. So I would only change colors, font sizes, etc.

Comment: so do you recommend copy and change a theme in designer and change the css there? but with this i should made a new theme for each app ? i changed some things like width, paddings of some buttons with id

Comment: If you want to change the look and feel of a single app, do it like you just did. If you want to change the look of all apps over your whole Launchpad, then copy the theme and change whatever you like.

Comment: I would strongly discourage using IDs for styling UI5 controls. In CSS, you should use the DOM IDs which are autogenerated by UI5 (and are fairly ugly and also not necessarily stable). You should use custom classes or maybe custom data instead. See the SDK topic about this: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/9d87f925dfbb4e99b9e2963693aa00ef